# Return a value from sql

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Im trying move my sql connection to a method in a class file and return a value to check if the username existing in the db and display as text in the page to show others that the username exist. How should i modify my aspx .cs page to display error as a label in the aspx code page?

My original code on the aspx .cs page:

```
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            con.Open();

            bool exists = false;

            // create a command to check if the username exists
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select count(*) from Member where UserName = @UserName", con))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("UserName", UNameTxtBox.Text);
                exists = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar() > 0;
            }

            // if exists, show a message error
            if (exists)
                ExistLabel.Text = "UserName exists";
```

My class file code:

```
public static string searchusername(string username)
{
    connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    {
        conn.Open();

        bool exists = false;

        using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("select count(*) from Member where UserName = @UserName", conn))
        {
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
            exists = (int)comm.ExecuteScalar() > 0;
        }
        if (exists)
        {
            return "exist";
        }
        return null;
    }
```

And the code in my aspx cs file:

```
 MemberDB.searchusername(UNameTxtBox.Text);
```

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: There is no error but how can i pass the exist back to the aspx page and display it if the username exist in the db?

Comment: You should provide your aspx / designer page code where you want to put it for display..

Comment: I want to display as a label in the designer page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `label` in your page and set the `Text` property of label to the `value` `returned` by the method.

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="userExists"></asp:Label>
```

And than in code behind do like this

```
userExists.Text = MemberDB.searchusername(UNameTxtBox.Text);
```

Comment: Small remark : in my opinion it's better to use a `Literral` in this case. A `Label` will translate to and HTML `<label>` tag if attribute `AssociatedControlID` is specified, and be surrounded by a (most probably useless) `<span>` tag if that attribute is not specified.

Comment: @Bartdude thanks for the comment i agree but OP here is wanting a label so just added code for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static bool searchusername(string username)
{
    connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        conn.Open();

        bool exists = false;

        using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("select count(*) from Member where UserName = @UserName", conn))
        {
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
            exists = (int)comm.ExecuteScalar() > 0;
        }
        return exists;
    }
```

In your page

```
if(MemberDB.searchusername(UNameTxtBox.Text))
{
    ExistLabel.Text = "UserName exists";
}
```